# My website doesn't provide 404 errors

Tags: seo, url, 301-redirect, 404

My website doesn't provide 404 errors.

If you were to type in: clientsforcounsellors.com/dlkforiereg or pretty much any gibberish page that doesn't exist, you'd be redirected to my home page.

1. Why could this be happening?
2. Is it bad for SEO?
3. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is your site hosted?   Can you share your sites configuration (for example the `.htaccess` file if it has one)?

Comment: Bluehost is hosting it. There's nothing in the .htaccess file.

Comment: you could use your browsers developer-tools to monitor ("keep logs on navigation" setting ON) what goes over the wire - like a 301/302 "moved permanently/temporarily" message and maybe you should (try to) override the preconfigured settings of your hoster with some entries into .htaccess - something simple first to ensure they even give you those capabilites .. rewriterules can be tricky to get just right ;-)

Comment: Do you have any redirects configure from your Bluehost control panel?   https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/redirecting-web-page

Comment: Your site isn't redirecting to the home page.  `curl --head 'https://clientsforcounsellors.com/dlkforiereeeeeg'` shows `HTTP/2 200`.   If I visit that URL, I see the contents of the home page, but there is no redirect involved.      Are you sure there is absolutely nothing in your `.htaccess` file?   Configuring your site to act this way would be done from `.htaccess` 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yeah, there really is nothing there.

Comment: Whatever can be done in .htaccess can also be done in Apache configuration files (httpd.conf).   Since you are with a shared host, you probably don't have access to that unless you got a virtual private server (VPS).    Do you have access to the Apache configuration files?   Or is there a setting in the Bluehost control panel that you tweaked that might have cause this behavior?